# Application Instead of running redirects itself into Debugging mode

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have an android application,it takes me in unusual situation when I going to run my application it automatically redirects itself to debugging mode, and debugging screen is displayed whenever I want to run the application from eclipse to my cell phone,I removed all the breakpoints, I uninstalled my application, remove my project from workspace then again add it to but can't get success, I haev already tested all of the techniques which may help me to get out of this problem but nothing works for me.

Comment: Did you check in your developer settings of your phone that you do not have your app list in debug

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line in manifest file

`android:debuggable = false`

For more info visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug)